# Thingsboard Edge Setup

Tags: thingsboard

I want to set up a ThingsBoard Edge, and it will be receiving data from 450 devices concurrently every 3 seconds. What settings/parameters on ThingsBoard should I change or use?

I followed the setup instructions in the ThingsBoard installation documentation, but some of the data didn't appear on the edge.